# Why does .html() move my content instead of cloning in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am learning jQuery now and I bumped into this question.

Here's my code.

When I click on the Pick button, all of `<li>` element in the A List and B List are gone and insert into `#demo` list.

```
  <body>
    <button id="btnPickItem">Pick</button>

    <hr />

    <div>
      <h4>A List</h4>
      <ul id="aList">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4>B list</h4>
      <ul id="bList">
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="demo"></div>

    <script>
      btnPickItem.onclick = function () {
        $("#demo").html($("li"));
      };
    </script>
  </body>
```

First I was thinking it would copy all the `<li>` elements to the `#demo` list.

Later I tried `$("#demo").append($("li").clone());` and it worked.

so I was wondering does using .html($()) in jQuery work like selecting element and move them into new list?

or how to explain what actually happened? or that's what selectors in jQuery do?

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation says that the argument to `.html()` can either be a string or a function that returns a string. Passing other types is not specified, but it acts like `.append()` after emptying the target element.

Comment: `$("#demo").append($("li").html());` would be the intended way. Don't supply an element, supply an HTML string as Barmar mentioned. Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Thanks @Barma for the answers. I was stucking at this problem and curious why it would and would not work yesterday therefore forgot what I sent into the function was not what it needed to be.